# Nautilus Script for ESET scanner

Tags: gnome-terminal, nautilus-script

I have installed Eset antivirus as per the instructions given [here](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2653&locale=en_US) All is working well but instead of gui I want to have a responsive terminal option available too thus I created a symlink via:

`sudo ln -s /opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_scan /bin/eset`

now I can siimply run `eset <destination>` along with further flags to get the job done. Provided the eset by default scan all subdirectories in said destination I want to hava a nautilus script that sits in my context & whenever I want I right-click a folder (& using this script) be able to scan that folder.

Of coarse I want the terminal to remain open so that I can see the progress & logs, in my attempts the scan initiates but as soon as it is done terminal quits :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the only thing you like is for the terminal to remain there after the scan completed? That's pretty easy. In the last line of your script add the command `read`.

eg.

`#!/bin/bash`

`....Your script....`

`read`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer will still be relevant, since You posted Your question quite some time ago...

Nevertheless, I was wondering the same and came up with a solution I would like to share with others who would like to achieve the same:

(tested on Ubuntu-gnome 16.04 LTS, 4.4.0-62-generic)

#### 1.) Enable eset-NOD32 scan via the command terminal (as already posted by OP)

Add a symbolic link in /bin to the default installation directory ( /opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_scan) to allow for the execution of 'esets_scan' via the terminal command 'esets /DIRECTORY':

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_scan /bin/eset
```

#### 2.) Configure nautilus-actions to enable threat-scanning via 'right-click'

[Note: for this to work You will have to use the nautilus file manager.]

Install the nautilus file manager configuration tool: [nautilus-actions](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/nautilus-actions/)

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Once installed, we open **nautilus-actions** and configure the 'Eset-ThreatScan' action:

- create a new action (click on the '+')
- go to the 'Action' tab. Under 'Nautilus Item' check following options:

  - 'Display item in selection context menu'
  - Context label: type in 'Eset-ThreatScan'
  - 'Display item in the toolbar
  - 'Use same label for icon in the toolbar'
- go to the 'Command' tab. Under 'Command' enter the following specifications

  - Path: eset
  - Parameters: %B
  - Working directory: %d
- go to the 'Execution' tab. Under 'Execution mode' check the following:

  - 'Display output'

Save the configuration by clicking on the menu: 'File'>'Save'.

Close nautilus actions and restart nautilus (you may need to pkill nautilus):

```
pkill nautilus
```

#### 3.) Scan with eset via right-click

Simply 'right-click' on a selection (i.e. selected [multiple] folders or files) and select 'Nautilus Action actions'>'Eset - ThreatScan' in the in the up-popping 'right-click' menu.

The scan will be running silently in the background. Once the scan is finished, a pop-up will appear displaying the output-streams (including summary, errors and scan results, so the same as when run via the terminal).
You can close the pop-up by either clicking on 'OK', or pressing 'Alt'+'F4.

Hope this helps making Your life easier.
Cheers.